# How to be invisible in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-organization

I haven't seen anywhere to set my visibility status. Is there the possibility and is that available for normal (not business) organizations' users?

By being **invisible**, I mean the status that other users cannot detect when I am online, away and/or offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, it isn't possible to become invisible. Try looking it up at Trello Help pages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `+1`ed `:)`